Blazor CssScope generates weird css class
I was using MS docs to configure a custom scope identifier for my isolated css code.
I added this to my .csproj file
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Pages/Jobs.razor.css" CssScope="jobs-scope" />
  </ItemGroup>

this is my Jobs.Razor.css file
::deep .blurry-dialog-background {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

This is how I would like to reference the css class in my Jobs.Razor.cs
DialogOptions options = new()
{
    ClassBackground = "blurry-dialog-background[jobs-scope]",
    CloseButton = true,
};

But what I can see using chrome dev tools is, that the generated file looks like this:
/* _content/Project/Pages/Jobs.razor.rz.scp.css */
[jobs-scope] .blurry-dialog-background {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}

So how do I correctly identify the css so I can use it in my code? All auto generated css scopes look different and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if it is a bug?

Are you use MudBlazor? If you use , you can change this line  BackgroundClass = "blurry-dialog-background". You can check the API url:https://mudblazor.com/components/dialog#blurry-dialog
If  you don’t use  MudBlazor and have Child component, you should  change this line  ClassBackground = "blurry-dialog-background".  you can add a div  wrap  all html or add a div wrap the child  component in the parent  component
If you have no Child component,you can remove ::deep. The ::deep pseudo-element affects where the scope attribute is applied to the rule. When you define a CSS rule in a scoped CSS file, the scope is applied to the right most element by default.
use ::deep ,the Generated css like this,it doesn't work.

remove ::deep,the Generated css like this,it works.


Thanks for taking the time to investigate this. I can confirm that removing the ::deep attribute actually generates the file correctly on my end too!
